# No answer from Editor

Tags: publications

I submitted a paper to an editor of well-known journal via email. It has been almost a month I did not hear anything, even not an acknowledgement from the editor, though I sent them 2 follow up emails.

What should I do?

Comment: When did you send the last follow-up e-mail?

Comment: What do the journal submission instructions say?  I've never submitted a paper by e-mail to editor, but perhaps customs differ by field.

Comment: Following the Author's instruction, I submitted it visa email. Journal is Published by Taylors and Francis. I sent the paper on 26th April, yet I did not get any acknowledgement. I sent a follow up email on 4th May, still no acknowledgement and then another follow up email on 13th May. Still no reply.

Answer (score 7):

Before doing anything else, I would recommend doing the following:

- Check that the answers haven't accidentally made their way into your spam folder (if your email client has one).
- Check that you sent the emails to the correct address. (If you get the domain name wrong, you might not get a response back at all!)

If neither of these are the cause of the problem, then I would recommend that you contact the publisher, rather than the editor—something has clearly gone amiss. At the very least, you should have received an email acknowledging that the submission is complete.

If, on the other hand, you are waiting for the reviews to be returned, that can certainly take much longer than a month, and a little patience is in order.